# Why does the webContentLink access I get through the http interface of the Google cloud disk list report 404

Tags: google-drive-api

I obtained the file download url through the following interface, and the corresponding field is webContentLink, but why did I return a 404 status code when I accessed this download url. I have tested this problem only with some of these accounts. There is no idea to solve this problem now.

interface address:https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/files/list?hl=en&authuser=1

Answer (score 0):

According to their docs, `WebContentLink` is only available for files with binary content in Google Drive.

If you want to download all kind of file then use the `files.get` method with the ID of the file to download and set the `alt=media` URL parameter

Reference: https://developers.google.com/drive/api/guides/manage-downloads#download_a_file_stored_on_google_drive